# Is it possible to enforce a Unique Constraint on a Dataset comprised of joins

Tags: mysql, relational-theory, constraint

I am playing around with an idea to describe friendships in a system, and I am wondering about constraints. I currently have a database that looks like this:

`Users:`

```
+---------+-------------------------+
| User ID | (joined, password, etc) |
+---------+-------------------------+
| ALICE   | (normally numeric, but alpha for examples sake)
+---------+
| BOB     |
+---------+
| CARL    |
+---------+
```

`Friendships:`

```
+---------------+----------------------------------+
| Friendship ID | (date started, awesomeness, etc) |
+---------------+----------------------------------+
| 1             |
+---------------+
| 2             |
+---------------+
| 3             |
+---------------+
| 4             |
+---------------+
```

`Friendship Members:`

```
+---------+---------------+
| User ID | Friendship ID |
+---------+---------------+
| ALICE   | 1             |
+---------+---------------+
| BOB     | 1             |
+---------+---------------+
| ALICE   | 2             |
+---------+---------------+
| CARL    | 2             |
+---------+---------------+
| BOB     | 3             |
+---------+---------------+
| ALICE   | 3             |
+---------+---------------+
```

What I am looking for is a constraint that could perform a lookup on the `Friendship Members`, join them through their common `Friendship ID`, and ensure that the resultant dataset is unique (i.e. No two friendships with the same Members).

At this stage, it is assumed that a Friendship will only have 2 members. I have searched for a way to try to enforce that as a Constraint, but have had little success, so that is secondary at this point.

I was thinking that if this cannot be enforced natively by the database, I can always assemble a statement to find and remove non unique entities, but I was hoping to find a way to keep it entirely database side.

***SOLUTION***

As it was quickly answered, here is the implemented solution for others who are interested:

`ON INSERT TRIGGER`:

```
BEGIN
    SET @memberCount = (SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM `FriendshipMembers`
          WHERE `FriendshipID` = NEW.`FriendshipID`);

    CASE
        WHEN (@memberCount = 1)  THEN
            IF ((SELECT 1
                   FROM `FriendshipMembers`
                  WHERE `FriendshipID` = NEW.`FriendshipID`
                    AND `UserID`       = NEW.`UserID`) = 1) THEN
                SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'User already a part of the Friendship';
            END IF;

            SET @secondUserID = (SELECT `UserID`
                                   FROM `FriendshipMembers`
                                  WHERE `FriendshipID` = NEW.`FriendshipID`);
            IF ((SELECT COUNT(*)
                   FROM `FriendshipMembers` FM1
             INNER JOIN `FriendshipMembers` FM2
                     ON FM1.`FriendshipID` = FM2.`FriendshipID`
                    AND FM1.`UserID`      != FM2.`UserID`
                  WHERE FM1.`UserID`       = NEW.`UserID`
                    AND FM2.`UserID`       = @secondUserID) > 0) THEN
                SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'This Friendship already exists';
            END IF;

        WHEN (@memberCount > 1) THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Too many members';

        ELSE BEGIN END;
    END CASE;
END;
```

`ON UPDATE TRIGGER`:

```
BEGIN
    SET @memberCount = (SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM `FriendshipMembers`
          WHERE `FriendshipID` = NEW.`FriendshipID`);

    CASE
        WHEN (@memberCount = 2)  THEN
            IF ((SELECT 1
                   FROM `FriendshipMembers`
                  WHERE `FriendshipID` = NEW.`FriendshipID`
                    AND `UserID`       = NEW.`UserID`) = 1) THEN
                SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'User already a part of the Friendship';
            END IF;

            SET @secondUserID = (SELECT `UserID`
                                   FROM `FriendshipMembers`
                                  WHERE `FriendshipID` = NEW.`FriendshipID`
                                    AND `UserID`      != OLD.`UserID`);
            IF ((SELECT COUNT(*)
                   FROM `FriendshipMembers` FM1
             INNER JOIN `FriendshipMembers` FM2
                     ON FM1.`FriendshipID` = FM2.`FriendshipID`
                    AND FM1.`UserID`      != FM2.`UserID`
                  WHERE FM1.`UserID`       = NEW.`UserID`
                    AND FM2.`UserID`       = @secondUserID) > 0) THEN
                SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'This Friendship already exists';
            END IF;

        WHEN (@memberCount > 2) THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Too many members';

        ELSE BEGIN END;
    END CASE;
END;
```

Comment: Will there always be 2 members in each relationships?

Comment: Yes, the friendship only exists between 2 people, I am going to be using a separate table (based on this, but without that limit) to handle Friendship Groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create 
*before insert/ before update* trigger/s on Friendship Members table

table Friendships has nothing to do with the relation so you probably want so leave it aside for now.

the trigger should check

1. id X can not have relation with id X
2. if id X is in relation with id Y than do not create relation between id Y and id X

[triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Comment: Sweet, that also works for enforcing the Constraint of the number of Friendship Members, cheers

Comment: nice triggering, mate!

just a note:

on update trigger will work every time you update something in the source table.

Normally  what you need is an event triggered for a single column, which I usually implement using:
if (old.value <> new.value) (you might want to use <=> instead with NOT ) than ...

Comment: ah, good point. I should modify that to perform two separate tests, one if the User value changes (which it already does), and one if the Friendship value changes

Comment: exactly, mate! ;)